January, 2020: Will Chinese.SE shut down any time soon?
There's been multiple anti-community happenings on Stack Exchange recently (informally "The Mess").  After multiple recent surprise changes (ads; CC BY-SA 4.0; HNQ; question rep.; CoC; mod. reinstatement), and after the legal settlement concerning Monica's surprise dediamonding, a few days ago we were shocked to learn of the dismissals (from paid employment) of Stack Exchange community team member Shog9 (who was here just recently) and Robert Cartaino (basically the head of Area 51) and its aftermath.
These dismissals (further) support the idea that at least some sites will probably soon shut down:

Area 51 (not many new sites are being created nowadays) and
Meta.SE (which would be replaced by the newly-arrived The Loop after staff complaints of hypercritical feedback).

To my knowledge, Stack Exchange staff have not denied either of these could happen.  (There's also suggestive StackOverflow posts about removing Hot Meta Posts and adding sites to StackOverflow.)
Stack Exchange's overall behavior indicates it is refocusing on profit-making ventures (Jobs, Teams, advertising), and it may make further anti-community steps.  (Predicting this, some users are currently creating an alternative, called Codidact.)
Consequently on Meta.SE, user HDE 226868 asked After the recent CM departures, are there plans to shut down network sites or Area 51? but we've heard nothing official so far.
In any case, all I really want to know is...
Question: Will Chinese.SE shut down any time soon?
Why should I spend time curating the site if it's at risk of being closed?  It seems reasonable to believe further anti-community decisions will happen.  I'm here to make the Internet a better place, but maybe this no longer aligns with Stack Exchange's motivations.

Maybe you should ask this on meta meta, I'm not sure what insights we could provide here. -Or- perhaps the content on the After the recent CM departures, are there plans to shut down network sites or Area 51? question are the best answers we are going to get? You might also be curious to read through this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342224/260869

I posted this to meta.SE: Remember when Stack Exchange and the Community worked side-by-side to “make the Internet a better place”? Can we go back to this please?.  It's not exactly the same.  We'll see how things turn out, I guess.  (The fact that the question is not immediately met by a flood of messages saying "that's ridiculous" says something, though.)

This might really be the beginning of a new era for SE. No one can blame you for not wanting to polish the brass.

It looks like we're okay for now:

We have ideas for how to better integrate technical content from across SE with the knowledge sharing that happens on SO, and vice versa. For the broader SE community discussing non-technical topics, we have no plans to change anything at the moment.
Pchandrasekar, Stack Exchange CEO, 21 January 2020

This has now been affirmed more strongly:

Last week the CM team met with Teresa, our new CPO, and we talked about what the future of the network looks like. The conversation started off with the understanding that shutting down SE sites was off the table. So, unless we stumble upon the usual reasons for shutting down a site — that is, if no one's willing to step up to help moderate it — everything will keep going as usual.
JNat♦, 27 February, 2020

